# Binary Algorithm not working in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, binary

My code runs, but it doesn't refresh the total or one of the numbers being used because it keeps adding on to the number
I have tried to refresh the number for 'total' and 'i', but they don't work, what do I do?

```js
var totalB;
var binOneMul = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    totalB = 0;
    $("#subB").click(function () {
        var binOneVal = document.getElementsByName("typeB")[0].value;
        var binOneStore = binOneVal.split("");
        for (i = 0; i < binOneStore.length; i++) {
            var binOneStoreTwo= binOneStore.reverse();
            var binOneNum = binOneStoreTwo[i];
            var binOneConv = binOneNum * Math.pow(2, i);
            binOneMul.push(binOneConv);
        }
        for (k = 0; k < binOneMul.length; k++) {
            totalB += binOneMul[k];
        }
        document.getElementById("parB").innerHTML = totalB;
        binOneStoreTwo = [];
        binOneStore = [];
        binOneMul = [];
        binOneVal = [];
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divB">
    <input type="text" name="typeB"></input>
    <button id="subB">Click to Convert from Binary</button>
    <br>
    <p id="parB"></p>
</div>
<div id="divBt">
    <input type="text" name="typeBt"></input>
    <button name="subBt">Click to Convert to Binary</button>
    <p id="parBt"></p>
</div>
<div id="divH">
    <input type="text" name="typeH"></input>
    <button name="subH">Click to Convert from Hexadecimal</button>
    <p id="parH"></p>
</div>
<div id="divHt">
    <input type="text" name="typeHt"></input>
    <button name="subHt">Click to Convert to Hexadecimal</button>
    <p id="parHt"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: _convert binary to decimal.._ Why not use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)?

Comment: How would `parseInt` help at all?

Comment: `parseInt` just could _convert binary to decimal_, as I wrote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day.

Your code has some mistakes:

1. **$("#subB")**. Selector # using to find elements by id
2. **document.getElementsByName("typeB")** turns bask array of elements. So you should use **document.getElementsByName("typeB")[0]**. Better, you should check length of array before using it.
3. **pow(2, i)** is part of object Math. So you should write **Math.pow(2, i)**
4. **document.getElementById("parB").innerHTML = total;** Here you try to assign undefined variable. Right version is **document.getElementById("parB").innerHTML = totalB;**

Best regards.

Comment: I edited my code (and my question) and it still is having troubles

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the array of bits first, as the 1's place is the last bit in the array.